# Adding a new Point into the correct position in an Array of Points

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, graphics, canvas

I have a polygon with several points and a new point has to be added. The existing points are stored in an array:

```
var points = [
    {x: 0, y:0},
    {x: 100, y: 0},
    {x: 100, y: 100},
    {x: 0, y: 100}
];
```

How do you determine which position of the array this `newPoint` should be added into?

**Attempt:** I iterated through all the existing points and calculate `newPoint`'s distance from them, and sorted the existing points into an array containing the index of these points, in order of increasing distance from `newPoint`.

Following my current attempt's method, the next step will be to check whether the 2 closest points are adjacent. If they are, add the `newPoint` between them in the `points` array. If they are not adjacent, well I'm kind of stuck here :) How do you check whether the 2 points are adjacent?

Any help greatly appreciated!

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y3kmm/

---

The reason why the order matters is because Shapes are usually drawn in a clockwise manner. Here's a jsfiddle where the blue polygon had a point added at the correct place, and a red polygon with a point added at the end of the `points` array.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TyQXV/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the order matters because the polygon is drawn in a clockwise direction. So if a point thats supposed to be drawn earlier, is drawn at the end, the polygon gets distorted.

Comment: you don't really have to grow up the complexity of the program using sort: simply stored two initial points, considering them to be the closest, and then replace them as you iterate through the other points

Comment: I got something working; http://jsfiddle.net/hK3Kh/73/. I'm not entirely sure where the current algorithm fails and where it doesn't. I'll do some more tests and then I will be able to complete my answer.

Comment: This is generally stable, but does break at certain points. I assume as the polygon complexity and concavity increases, the algorithm will become less and less efficient. http://jsfiddle.net/qmBWV/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, let's take a closer look at polygons.

[image: Ted]

We'll call him Ted. When Ted (or a polygon in general) sees a point, he tries to assimilate it within himself. And for assimilation, he decides to give one of his many **sides** the honor of reaching out and **grabbing the point**. Now, Ted is busy with more important stuff, so the **sides** need to decide among themselves which one will do the good deed. I'll say it again; **sides**.

[image]

There we go, there's a point in Ted's vicinity, blissfully unaware that soon it's going to be consumed viciously. So, how do Ted's sides decide which one will snatch the point? Well, it needs to be fair game. The side which senses that the **perpendicular distance** from it to the point is the shortest will be the one to do it. **Shortest**. **Perpendicular**. **Distance**.

[image]

Assimilation complete!

Another thing to keep in mind is that polygons like Ted value survival over assimilation. The side with the shortest perpendicular distance from the point commences the assimilation only if it **does not cut through the other sides**. So, sides with only **valid** assimilation are considered. Otherwise, **bad things happen**.

[image]

There are two important points within my unnecessary spiel;

- The **side** to which we add the point should have the **shortest perpendicular distance** from the point.
- Apart from having the shortest perpendicular distance from the point, the addition of the point to this side should be **valid**. This is important, after all, we don't want to perpetrate mass polygon murder.

So, here's some pseudo-code;

```
For each side S in polygon P
Do
    d := perpendicularDistanceFromSide(S, point);
    If d is less than shortestPerpendicularDistance
    Do
        If additionIsValid(S, point, P)
        Do
            shortestPerpendicularDistance := d;
            index = S.index;
        End If
    End If
End For
```

Finding the perpendicular distance from the side is easily done;

```
var perpendicularDistance = function(side, point) {
    //Find direction vector of side
    var dir = {x: side.p2.x - side.p1.x, y: side.p2.y - side.p1.y};
    var m = Math.sqrt(dir.x*dir.x + dir.y*dir.y);
    if(m !== 0) {
        d.x = d.x/m;
        d.y = d.y/m;
    }

    //Find position vector of point, from side
    var pVec = {x: point.x - side.p1.x, y: point.y - side.p1.y};

    //Absolut of cross product of dir and pVec. 
    //It's essentially |pVec|*Sin(q), q is the angle between
    //dir and pVec.
    return Math.abs(dir.x*pVec.y - dir.y*pVec.x);
};
```

Now, let's look at validity. If, after adding the point to the polygon, the new sides cut through any of the other sides, it's over for the little guy. We need to ensure that our algorithm accounts for this.

I thought up two versions for this; one cheap and one expensive.

**Method 1**:

If there is little to none concavity in the polygon, this method works perfectly. This method only checks that the new sides do not intersect the sides adjacent to the old side.

Say we have a side `S`. It's two adjacent sides are `Sprev` and `Snext`. The two new sides are `S1p` and `S2p`. `S1p` and `Sprev` have the point `S.p1` in common. `S2p` and `Snext` have the point `S.p2` in common.

According to this method, the addition is valid if and only if there is no intersection between:

- `Sprev` and `S2p`
- `Snext` and `S1p`

So, this method works on rejection. If we can't find any intersection, the side `S` can add the point validly.

**[Method 1 Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/un6Qj/7/)**

**Method 2**:

Method 1 fails as the concavity of the polygon increases. So, we need to do further checking to ensure valid point addition.

This method is really an extension of Method 1. After finding that the pairs `Sprev` and `S2p`, and `Snext` and `S1p` are not intersecting, we check if the new sides are intersecting with all the other sides of the polygon (apart from `Sprev` and `Snext`, of course).

If the addition is not rejected after all the sides are checked, we are completely sure that this addition is valid.

The problem is, that while rejection is quick enough, reaching acceptance takes a long time, making this method quite expensive.

Furthermore, the complexity depends on the number of sides of the polygon. As the polygon complexity increases, checking validity will take more and more time.

**[Method 2 Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uaLGe/5/)**

I must note, the algorithm I used for checking line-segment intersection is taken from [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect). It's totally awesome.

And that's all I have. This is one way to do it, I must say. There might be another, better way which has not struck me yet. I hope you didn't terribly mind Ted. And also, thanks for asking a good question, I enjoyed it.

Answer (score 4):

As I said before, you don't really have to grow up the complexity of the program using sort: simply stored two initial points, considering them to be the closest, and then replace them as you iterate through the other point.

**However**, your problem have more than one possible solution; you must define more constraints to it.

For example, think of four points forming a square:

```
·-------·
|       |
|       |
|       |
·-------·
```

Now, add a point to a random position inside the polygon:

```
·-------·
|       |
| ·     |
|       |
·-------·
```

There are more than two possible orders that will, still, maintain your polygon convex:

```
·-------·
 \      |
  ·     |
 /      |
·-------·

·   ____·
|\ /    |
| ·     |
|       |
·-------·
```

Comment: I am trying out your suggestion and +1 for drawing them out in ASCII :)

Comment: haha, thanks; try to add some other constraints, and we'll be glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your calculation won't solve the issue you are experiencing.  For example, take the following two polygons:

```
var poly3 = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    x: 200,
    y: 100,
    points: [0,25,25,0,150,100,75,125],
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    name: 'poly',
    draggable: false
});
group.add(poly3);

var poly4 = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    x: 300,
    y: 100,
    points: [0,25,25,0,75,125,150,100],
    fill: 'yellow',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    name: 'poly',
    draggable: false
});
group.add(poly4);
```

The closest point is not necessarily the one that should be drawn next.

Answer (score 0):

`The reason why the order matters is because Shapes are usually drawn in a clockwise manner.`

You just answered your question. Where you add the new point depends on what shape you want and so has nothing to do with distance. You simple add the point at the location you want it to be drawn.

Say, do you already know what the shape should be or do you have to guess the shape based on where a user clicks the mouse? If you must guess, you may have to set a default behavior. Otherwise, give your user an additional parameter.